# c# Logmanager.Configure exception Method not found: 'System.String System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

In .net core 3.1 wpf app i want to configure nlog with the following code
I have appsettings.json

```
{
  "LogConfiguration": {
    "factoryAdapter": {
      "type": "Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog4412",
      "arguments": {
        "configType": "FILE",
        "configFile": "./nlog.config"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and in app.xaml.cs OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            LogConfiguration logConfiguration = new LogConfiguration();
            config.GetSection("LogConfiguration").Bind(logConfiguration);
            LogManager.Configure(logConfiguration);
```

when i call:

```
ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger<App>();
```

i get following Exception

```
Method not found: 'System.String System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()
```

anybody has a hint on this?

Comment: Try use this updated build instead: https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/pull/176 (Supporting NetCore). Alternative drop using Common Logging and use Microsoft Extension Logging or just NLog without any wrapper.

Comment: @Rolf Kristensen yes, the updated build works, thanks!